# py2exe - single file exe-tkinter program not executing

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe

I used below code to make execute of my program:

```
from distutils. core import *
import py2exe,sys,os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(options={'py2exe':{bundle_files':1,'compressed':True,'includes':["Tkinter",]}}'windows=['trial.py'],zipfile=None,)
```

It is creating single file `.exe`, but not executing.
same code with `bundle_file 3` (without single file) is working fine.

trial.py:

```
import Tkinter
Tkinter.Tk()
mainloop()
```

Please help me to create a single `.exe` file  for GUI program

Comment: how to with [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInstaller is a much easier option that can be used from the console. Just `pip install pyinstaller`, enter your program's directory, and `pyinstaller yourscript.py`.

I am confused that you say `trial.py` is working fine when I get an error on my machine. `mainloop()` needs to be replaced by `Tkinter.mainloop()`.

Comment: yes. i used from Tkinter import * . i dont know pyinstaller not working in my system. i am using 2.7 portable